# how to use OnPageScrollStateChanged in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I am stuck at a point where I need to hide the list view if the state of view pager is changed. i.e if I swipe from fragment 1 to fragment two in a view pager the I want my list view to hide. That might be achieved by OnPageScrollStateChanged by I dont know the implementation on xamarin studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following could be the approach for the ques

```
public class HomePageActivity : FragmentActivity, Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home);
var viewPager_up = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager_up);
viewPager_up.AddOnPageChangeListener (this);

}
public void OnPageScrollStateChanged (int state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnPageScrollStateChanged "+" "+state);
        }
        public void OnPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
Console.WriteLine ("OnPageScrolled "+" "+position);
}

        public void OnPageSelected (int position)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnPageSelected"+" "+position);


        }
}
```

Comment: Is that different from using events associated with the view pager: i.e: viewPager_up.PageSelected += ViewPagerOnPageSelected;

Answer (score 0):

For records : Here is how the events are popped.

```
OnPageScrollStateChanged state = 2 (SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)==> start scrolling 

onPageSelected ==> a page has been selected (before start scrolling to it), check pos.

onPageScrolled ==> called many times while scrolling (~50% for old pos, ~50% for new pos)

OnPageScrollStateChanged state = 0 (SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)==> on end scroll (settled)
```

For any one who came across!